# Testing of rocket heat shield on Earth

Tags: spacex, reentry, heat-shield

One Space Shuttle was destroyed due to failure of the insulation tiles. SpaceX is reportedly  using another technology, which replicates sweating , for wearing off the reentry heat. How is the effectiveness or efficiency of these reentry heat shields best simulated or tested on Earth?

Comment: Note that the sweaty Starship concept was abandoned long ago.

Comment: Perhaps nitpicky, but Columbia was not destroyed because of *tile failure*. It was lost because of *impact damage* to the *reinforced carbon-carbon* on the left wing leading edge.

Comment: Also nitpicky, the reinforced carbon-carbon was damaged during *ascent*, so no amount of ground-based testing would have been able to find anything.

Comment: @JörgWMittag there was a boatload of ground based testing done *after* the Columbia failure to check out tile and RCC repair kits.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ground testing of heatshield components and materials can and has been done in [arcjet facilities](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.ac.uk%2Fdownload%2Fpdf%2F227725366.pdf&psig=AOvVaw3m4UqccL2feWKqmDGLZyN4&ust=1604510829562000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKCUmuPy5uwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD).

[image]

(image [source](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/thermophysics-facilities-images))

An arcjet typically combines a super- or hyper- sonic wind tunnel with a large electrical heating device. "The
gases (typically air) pass through a nozzle aimed at
a test sample in vacuum, and flow over it, producing
a reasonable approximation of the surface
temperature and pressure and the gas enthalpy
found in a high velocity, supersonic flow of the kind
experienced by a vehicle on atmospheric entry."

[image]

(sourced from first link)

NASA Ames has four arcjet facilities in its [arcjet complex](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/thermophysics-facilities/arcjet-complex).  "The largest power supply can deliver 75 MW for 30 minute duration or 150 MW for 15 second
duration."

Johnson Space Center also had an [arcjet facility](https://roundupreads.jsc.nasa.gov/pages.ashx/119/Johnson%20Space%20Centers%20Arc%20Jet%20Facilities%20engineered%20human%20spaceflight%20programs%20for%20decades) that was last used heavily during [development of shuttle tile repair materials](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24336732_Arc_Jet_Screening_Tests_Of_Phase_1_Orbiter_Tile_Repair_Materials_and_Uncoated_RSI_High_Temperature_Emittance_Measurements) and procedures after the Columbia failure. It was closed in 2014 due to redundancy with the Ames facility.

[image]

(image [source](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/engineering/human_space_vehicle_systems/atmospheric_re-entry_materials/index.html))

The first link in this answer is a very good overview of arcjet testing and facilities, please see it for further reading.

Section 4 of the document "[Test Planning Guide
for
NASA Ames Research Center
Arc Jet Complex and Range Complex](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/tsf_test_planning_guide_revf.pdf)" contains a detailed description of the arcjet facilities at Ames.

Comment: Are there studies about how accurate and cost saving the data provided by these ground tests are, compared to semi or full scale 'in situ' tests ?

Comment: @qqjkztd I've seen a few papers about methodologies for correlating arcjet and flight environments: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20140000484/downloads/20140000484.pdf https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268563549_Ground-to-Flight_Traceability_Analysis_of_Arcjet_Testing_for_the_Crew_Exploration_Vehicle

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. +1

Comment: That slide is a bit strange when talking about voltage and giving power figures in brackets. 10 megawolt? :-P

Comment: @Arsenal It appears to be 20K VDC according to this document https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/tsf_test_planning_guide_revf.pdf

Comment: Great, thanks for that information.

Comment: @Arsenal I also assume they meant "lightning bolt", not "lightening bolt".  Spell check would've missed that one because both are valid words, but the meaning is quite different...

Comment: "The largest power supply can deliver 75 MW for 30 minute duration or 150 MW for 15 second duration." 75MW for 30mins implies 150MW for 15mins. Are you sure about "15 seconds" - does the higher power degrade something - or is that a typo?

Comment: @simonatrcl What you say makes sense, but I quoted it correctly.

Comment: @OrganicMarble What a pity. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 13):

To test a heatshield *properly*, you build a test article and reenter with it.

To test it adequately, you put it in a low pressure wind tunnel, and blast it with plasma blowtorches. Example [Ames research Arcjet facility](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/research/area-entry-systems.html) testing SpaceX's PICA heatshield material for the Dragon capsule.

[image]

To test it SpaceX style, you put a bunch of propane torches on it. This is an early test of SpaceX Starship heatshield tiles.
[image]

P.s.
The idea of transpiration-cooled heatshields is out of date. There is great uncertainty about just *what* SpaceX is actually going to use as heatshield, and how it is affixed to the Starship.
Recent test Hoppers have had some sort of hexagonal tiles affixed to them,
[image]
but these have not survived the launch or even static fire tests very well.
[image]
[Long article about the Starship heatshield tiles on Teslarati's website.](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-starship-heat-shield-prototype-robots/)

Comment: "but these have not survived the launch or even static fire tests very well" where did you find this information?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. +1

Comment: @qqjkztd from the forum at https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?board=72.0    To date, the heatshield tiles affixed to Hopper and some SNx test rockets have broken, or more often just fallen off during engine firings, possibly due to the backing/adhesive failing under vibration.